# HTML does not run function on click

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to use the distance formula to find the difference between two castle on a game. The game stores the castle coordinates in the following format
"l+k://coordinates?16321,16520&146" the coordinates of this castle would be 16321 & 16520. I have written a function to extract this information from two castle links and then use the distance formula to return the answer. However for some reason when this function is called in the website it does not return the expected result. Does anyone know why this might be happening. Please find my code below. I have also attached a JSFiddle.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/ajdxetod/

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lords &amp; Knights - Distance Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="distanceScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="heading">Distance Calculator</h1>

    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Castle Link One</legend>
            <input type="text" id="castle_one">
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Castle Link Two</legend>
            <input type="text" id="castle_two">
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="map_of_areadiv">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Is Map Of Area Researched</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" id="moa_checkbox" checked="true"><label for="moa_checkbox">Is "Map Of Area Researched in the Libary?</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="calculate_button">
        <button id="calculate" onclick="distanceCastles()">Calculate Distance</button>
    </div>

    <div class="distance_output">
        <fieldset id="castle_distance">
            <legend>Distance (in fields)</legend>
            <input type="text" id="output" placeholder="Click the Calculate Distance Button">
        </fieldset>
        <textarea id="troop_times"></textarea>
    </div>

</body>
```

distanceScript.js

```
var castleone;
var castletwo;
var x1;
var x2;
var y1;
var y2;
var distance = 0;

function distanceCastles() {
    castleone = document.getElementById("castle_one") ;
    castletwo = document.getElementById("castle_two") ;

    if (typeof castleone === "string" && castleone.length === 33) {
        x1 = castleone.substring(18, 23);
        y1 = castleone.substring(24, 29);

        x2 = castletwo.substring(18, 23);
        y2 = castletwo.substring(24, 29);

        distance = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2));

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = distance;      
    } 
    else if (typeof castleone !== "string" || castleone.length !== 33) {
        document.getElementById("troop_times").innerHTML = "Error: You have not entered valid castle links";
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById("troop_times").innerHTML = "Error: You have not entered valid castle links";
    }       

}
```

Comment: **(index):117 Uncaught ReferenceError: distance is not defined** Got this error

Comment: have you checked the console ?

Comment: @chhameed i ran this before with slightly different code and got that same error but am not getting it now. Ive added a screenshot of the console

Comment: Fix the javascript errors? It'll stop running your script if there's an error, soo...

Comment: "I have also attacked a JSFiddle" - typos can be fun sometimes. That was a typo, right? We don't need to give aid to a lost and forlorn JSFiddle somewhere looking for jar of rosin with which to repair itself...

Comment: @enhzflep :) yep that was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues

As what first answer stated the distance was declared as a variable first

You are comparing an html object with a string..You don't need to do this (See how I attempted it)

You are trying to insert out message without using using the property `innerHTML` OR `textContent`..

You can get the value of each input distance using `.value` property of input box

See snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Lords &amp; Knights - Distance Calculator</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="distanceScript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var castleone;
    var castletwo;
    var x1;
    var x2;
    var y1;
    var y2;

    function distance() {

      castleone = document.getElementById("castle_one");
      castletwo = document.getElementById("castle_two");

      if (castleone.value.length === 33) {
        x1 = castleone.value.substring(18, 23);
        y1 = castleone.value.substring(24, 29);

        x2 = castletwo.value.substring(18, 23);
        y2 = castletwo.value.substring(24, 29);

        distance = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
        console.log(distance);

        document.getElementById("output").value = distance;
      } else if (castleone.value.length !== 33) {
        document.getElementById("troop_times").innerHTML = "Error: You have not entered valid castle links";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("troop_times").innerHTML = "Error: You have not entered valid castle links";
      }

    }
  </script>

  <h1 class="heading">Distance Calculator</h1>

  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Castle Link One</legend>
      <input type="text" id="castle_one">
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Castle Link Two</legend>
      <input type="text" id="castle_two">
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div class="map_of_areadiv">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Is Map Of Area Researched</legend>
      <input type="checkbox" id="moa_checkbox" checked="true">
      <label for="moa_checkbox">Is "Map Of Area Researched in the Libary?</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div class="calculate_button">
    <button id="calculate" onclick="distance()">Calculate Distance</button>
  </div>

  <div class="distance_output">
    <fieldset id="castle_distance">
      <legend>Distance (in fields)</legend>
      <input type="text" id="output" placehodler="Click the Calculate Distance Button">
    </fieldset>
    <textarea id="troop_times"></textarea>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Top Man!! Thanks for help ive only just learnt Javascript so this is all pretty new to me

Comment: Welcome friend...have a gr8 day!

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a variable

```
var distance = 0;
```

And then you create a function with the same name

```
function distance () {
    // code...
}
```

and you wonder why you get an error. Rename either.

Comment: Silly me ive fixed that now.

Comment: But it still dose not return the expected result